# Can I create a breakable loop with currentTime of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a loop of a video and when I click some button break that loop to finish the video

```js
function stopIt() {
  document.getElementById('stopIt').classList.add('stop');
}

function loopy() {
  var vid = document.getElementById('front-video');

  if (vid.currentTime > 1) {
    vid.currentTime = 0;
    if (document.getElementById('stopIt').classList.contains('stop')) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<video class="d-none d-lg-block" id="front-video" autoplay onTimeUpdate="loopy()">
 <source src="video/front-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="col-12 front-box py-3 pl-4" id="stopIt" onClick="stopIt()"></div>
```

I have a box with the id `stopIt`, but actually the video doesn't return to the start, It does it when I erase the second if.

Any ideas, thanks!

Comment: There's no loop there.

Comment: As Randy said, there is not attribute to specify that the video should be looping

Comment: What is the purpose of `if (vid.currentTime > 1) {
    vid.currentTime = 0}`? Are you trying to loop 0-1 second of the media?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think you want to do this:

```
function loopy() {
  if (!document.getElementById('stopIt').classList.contains('stop')) {
    var vid = document.getElementById('front-video');
    if (vid.currentTime > 1) vid.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to loop from a specific begin time in media playback to a specific end time in media playback you can set the initial `src` of the `HTMLMediaElement` to the URL followed by a media fragment identifier.

The media element will pause at the end time of the media fragment identifier. You can use `pause` event, which is dispatched when a media element reaches the end time of a media fragment identifier, where `.load()` then `.play()` can be called to loop the media playback.

At `click` on `button` element, remove `pause` event handler from `button` element, store the `.currentTime` in a variable, remove the media fragment identifier from the `src` of the media element, call `.load()` on media element, set `.currentTime` to the stored `.currentTime` and then call `.play()`.

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
let [from, to] = [0, 1];
let loop = true;
let currentTime = 0;
const src = "http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm";
const handlePause = e => {
  if (loop) {
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }
}
const stopLoop = e => {
  if (loop) {
    loop = !loop;
    video.removeEventListener('pause', handlePause);
    currentTime = video.currentTime;
    video.src = video.src.replace(/#.+$/, '');
    video.load();
    video.currentTime = currentTime;
    video.play();
  }
}
button.addEventListener('click', stopLoop)
video.addEventListener('pause', handlePause);
video.src = `${src}#t=${from},${to}`
```

```html
<button>stop loop</button>
<video src="" muted="false" controls autoplay>
```